# Android: MediaRecorder front-facing camera outputs 144x176

Tags: android, resolution, android-mediarecorder

I can't change the video resolution on the output video from MediaRecorder.

- Using front-facing camera
- SurfaceView

**Activity**

```
CamcorderProfile mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH );
recorder.setCamera( camera );
recorder.setAudioSource( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER );
recorder.setVideoSource( MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT );
recorder.setOutputFormat( mProfile.fileFormat );
recorder.setAudioEncoder( mProfile.audioCodec );
recorder.setVideoEncoder( mProfile.videoCodec );
recorder.setOutputFile( tempFile.getPath() );
recorder.setOrientationHint( 270 );
recorder.setVideoFrameRate( mProfile.videoFrameRate );
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate( mProfile.videoBitRate );
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate( mProfile.audioBitRate );
recorder.setAudioChannels( mProfile.audioChannels );
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate( mProfile.audioSampleRate );
```

The quality of the preview is crystal clear and working perfectly but the output video is low-res and grainy.

Using `recorder.setVideoSize( XXX, XXX );` gives me this error:

> E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19

**How can I get my output to have higher resolution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem (for now atleast) by getting the width/height parameters from the camera preview.

```
int videoWidth = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
int videoHeight = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
```

And then by using

```
recorder.setVideoSize( videoWidth, videoHeight );
```

This makes the output the same as the camera preview.

### EDIT:

If you keep the ratio right and be around 500x500 I think you can get any of the supported size around it by doing this:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
Camera.Size size = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get( 0 );
for ( Camera.Size s : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() ) {
    Log.e( "SIZE:", s.width + "x" + s.height );
    if ( s.width > 500 ) // from high to low res
        size = s;
}
Log.e( "SIZE", "Selected size: " + size.width + "x" + size + " (width still over 500)" );   
parameters.setPreviewSize( size.width, size.height );
camera.setParameters( parameters );
```

**Output**

> SIZE: 1920x1080
>
> SIZE: 1440x1080
>
> SIZE: 1280x960
>
> SIZE: 1280x720
>
> SIZE: 960x720
>
> SIZE: 864x480
>
> SIZE: 768x432
>
> SIZE: 720x480
>
> SIZE: 640x480
>
> SIZE: 320x240
>
> SIZE: 176x144
>
> Selected size: 640x480 (width still over 500)